# Python: Problem with SciPy solve_bvp ODE function

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I´m working on solving a system of ODE´s and have some problems to understand how to correctly set the boundary conditions which (maybe) relates to me not getting any solution.

I need to solve these equations for a high x value down to x~0:

[image: differential equations]

and the following boundary conditions:

v(x=1) = 1   &   a(x=1) = 2

The code I wrote sofar looks like this:

```
def func(x, r):
    v, a = r
    dvdx = ( ((x - v)*a - 2/x ) * (x - v) ) / ( (x - v)**2 - 1 )
    dadx = ( (a - 2/x * (x - v)) * (x - v) )*a / ( (x - v)**2 - 1 )
    return dvdx, dadx

def bc(rv, ra):
    return np.array((rv[1], ra[1]-2))

x = np.linspace(0.1, 100, 1000)
y = np.zeros((2, x.size))

sol = solve_bvp(func, bc, x, y)
```

But when I execute the code I get devision by 0 errors. Which makes sense, since the denominator of my equation will be 0 for x=1. But shouldn't the boundary conditions account for that?

Comment: At the moment your implemented boundary conditions read as `v(0.1)=0` and `v(100)=2`. // The condition you give are at the same point `x=1`, so that you have an initial-value problem that should be solved with the IVP solver `solve_ivp`. To get a solution in both directions, you need two calls to it. // You might still want to use some de-singularization by a slight change of division from `1/u` to `u/(eps+u^2)`, even if the solution does not come close to such points.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ah I see, the explanation and examples from the SciPy doku weren't really helpfull regarding the `bc()` function, but yours defintely was.  I will try with `solve_ivp`, thank you very much.

Comment: I messed up the index, it should be `a(0.1)` and `a(100)`, as the `[1]` component is the second one.